# Framework for filtering dirty request in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I have been using Node for our web app and express middleware.
I tried to test the application for any injections and other dirty requests.
Some of the patterns in the request I tried are as follows.

1) region=true%2Cres.setHeader%28%22WhiteHat%22%2C%22Test%22%29
2)region=..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fwinnt%2Fsystem32%2Fcmd.exe%3Fdir
3)region=%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fhosts

Which npm module could help filter out these request ? I tried filter-content and helmet but helmet does not have an option to catch these kind of request.

Appreciate if anyone has evaluated a module for this.

Thx a lot

Comment: How will you use the value of `region`? What is it for?

Comment: noisypixy region is a query param I use to to get region specific details from mongodb